# How to untar file in node.js

Tags: node.js, tar

There are some untar libraries, but I cannot get them working.

My idea would be something like

```
untar(bufferStreamOrFilePath).extractToDirectory("/path", function(err){})
```

Is something like this available?

Comment: `require('child_process').exec('tar -xf /path', function(err) {});`

Comment: Sure, but I would obviously like to do that without spawning another process.

Comment: Performing a CPU intensive task in the event loop is not what node was designed for, it is what `tar` was designed for.

Comment: As it is part of our build tool, I don't care about halting the loop. OTOH, I'd like this to work i.e. in non-unix environments (read: win users).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just an update on this answer, instead of `node-tar`, consider using [`tar-fs`](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-fs) which yields a significant performance boost, as well as a neater interface.

```
var tarFile = 'my-other-tarball.tar';
var target = './my-other-directory';

// extracting a directory
fs.createReadStream(tarFile).pipe(tar.extract(target));
```

Answer (score 6):

The [tar-stream](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-stream) module is a pretty good one:

```
var tar = require('tar-stream')
var fs = require('fs') 

var extract = tar.extract();
extract.on('entry', function(header, stream, callback) {
    // make directories or files depending on the header here...
    // call callback() when you're done with this entry
});

fs.createReadStream("something.tar").pipe(extract)

extract.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('done!')
});
```

Comment: I don't get what the stream should be. I have (inside a file input handler) `event.target.files?.item(0)?.stream().pipeTo(extract)`, but the TS compiler complains that `extract` is not of type `WritableStream<Uint8Array>`. edit: never mind, it's answered below. TL;DR, use `readable-web-to-node-stream`.

Answer (score 2):

A function to extract a base64 encoded tar fully in memory, with the assumption that all the files in the tar are utf-8 encoded text files.

```html
const tar=require('tar');
let Duplex = require('stream').Duplex;

function bufferToStream(buffer) {
    let stream = new Duplex();
    stream.push(buffer);
    stream.push(null);
    return stream;
}


module.exports=function(base64EncodedTar){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const buffer = new Buffer.from(base64EncodedTar, "base64");

        let files={};

        try{

            bufferToStream(buffer).pipe(new tar.Parse())
                .on('entry', entry => {
                    let file={
                        path:entry.path,
                        content:""
                    };
                    files[entry.path]=file;
                    entry.on('data', function (tarFileData) {
                        file.content += tarFileData.toString('utf-8');
                    });

                    // resolve(entry);
                }).on('close', function(){
                  resolve(files);
                });
        } catch(e){
            reject(e);
        }

    })

};
```

Comment: finally! after a long long long time and many tries and packages, I came across this comment!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the `tar-stream` answer, that seemed to be the simplest to use in the browser with jest-tested code. Comparing the node libraries based on my trying to implement a project:

- `tar`: Fairly easy to use on files, or buffers as in or Gudlaugur Egilsson's answer. It had some annoying webpack polyfill issues that I had trouble with when putting it into a react app.
- `js-untar`: This was pretty annoying to set up for `jest` testing because it uses web workers and blob URLs, which jest does not directly support. I didn't proceed to getting it working in the browser, though it may work fine there. In order to get jest tests working, I had to use `jsdom-worker-fix`, and it was *very* slow in that environment. (It may be faster in-browser.)
- `tar-stream` combined with `gunzip-maybe` seems to be fairly performant in browser, and doesn't have any issues with being used in jest tests. Worked fine on multi-hundred megabyte tarballs I tried.

This code extracts a tar or tar.gz stream:

```js
var tar = require("tar-stream");
const gunzip = require("gunzip-maybe");

exports.unTar = (tarballStream) => {
  const results = {};
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var extract = tar.extract();

    extract.on("entry", async function (header, stream, next) {
      const chunks = [];
      for await (let chunk of stream) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      }
      results[header.name] = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      next();
    });

    extract.on("finish", function () {
      resolve(results);
    });
    tarballStream.pipe(gunzip()).pipe(extract);
  });
};
```

Then in browser, you can use `readable-web-to-node-stream` to process a tarball fetched in the browser.

```js
const { ReadableWebToNodeStream } = require("readable-web-to-node-stream");
const response = await fetch(url, headers);
const extracted = await unTar(new ReadableWebToNodeStream(response.body));
```

Comment: Note that it works for the version 2.* of `readable-web-to-node-stream`. I couldn't figure out how to do that with the version 3.