# How can i read a json file in gzip?

Tags: node.js, gzip

There is an archive format gzip. There are json files. We need to get each file in turn , to do with it and what is written in the other gzip. I realized that I need to use the standard library createReadStream and zlib.

Comment: Depends, were they tar'd before they were gzipped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, following the example from https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_examples the following process could be done for a single gzipped file:

```
var unzip = zlib.createUnzip();
var fs = require('fs');
var inp = fs.createReadStream('input.json.gz');
var out = fs.createWriteStream('output.json');

inp.pipe(unzip).pipe(out);
```

However if there are multiple files within a gzip, I am not sure how one would go about doing that. I could not find documentation to do that and the only way I found that multiple files could be unzipped from a gzip file in node is if they were tar'd first. A process for unzipping tar.gz in node can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690613/how-to-untar-file-in-node-js). Following that example, one could do something like this:

```
var unzip = zlib.createUnzip();
var fs = require('fs');
var tar = require('tar-fs');
var inp = fs.createReadStream('input.tar.gz');
var out = './output'; // output directory

inp.pipe(unzip).pipe(tar.extract(out));
```