# tar file extraction nodejs npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, extract, tar

I am trying to extract a tar file, that I will receive from the web-browser client onto a SUSE server. I have installed tar.gz npm for doing my stuff. But it always throws the same error. Below is the function.

```
function extract(){
    var name = "C:\\MyDrive\\parsing\\1.zip";
    targz().extract(name, 'C:\\MyDrive', function(err){
    if(err)
        console.log('Something is wrong ', err.stack);
    console.log('Job done!');
    });
}
```

Below is the error.

```
\root\server>node test.js
Something is wrong  Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:370:17)
Job done!
```

Well this error is coming even in Windows also. When I create a tar file in windows and extract the same tar file in windows with the same function above. I believe either I am not using the npm currectly.

Is their any other npm and a working sample code for the same, which can extract the tar file uploaded by client. Extraction need to be achieved through some nodejs npm in javascript.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690613/how-to-untar-file-in-node-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to untar file in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690613/how-to-untar-file-in-node-js)

Answer (score -1):

There are few many modules for zipping and unzipping in node.js here this could be helpful - [unzip](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip)

```
fs.createReadStream(name).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: '/home/outputpath' }));
```